# KeywordQuery and Refiners: How to specify a RangeMapping Refiner?

Tags: search, fast-search, keywordquery, refiner

I need to use the KeywordQuery class to connect to a FAST Search Server. I still want to be able to display refiners (much like the default Refiner Web Part).

The default refiner web part supports a RangeMapping type of custom filter for managed properties (which is use with the write managed property to filter based on date ranges "Today", "This Week", "This month" ...). These ranges overlap.

When requesting refiners using KeywordQuery, one adds the refiner as a string "write(discretize=manual/2012-01-01/2012-02-01)".

How do I specify a range mapping here? Note that in the discretize sample, the buckets do not overlap. I need a filter where the ranges DO overlap.

(I am not looking for the custom filter definition-xml for the refiner web part ... I know how that looks ... I just need to know how it gets translated)

The best documentation for refiners and KeywordQuery is here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg984547.aspx but no word about how range mappings are encoded.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set CustomRefinementIntervals property on KeywordQuery